# mysql server is not sending result set back after query execution to client and staying in sending data state

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, java

When I pass a query from my Java application to mysql server, it stays in `Sending Data` state and not returning result set back to application.

When I execute the same query in SQLYog directly, it works fine and returns 1000 row(s) 
with following details

```
Execution Time : 21.060 sec
Transfer Time  : 3 min 11 sec
Total Time     : 3 min 33 sec
```

I am not getting any kind of exception for debugging.

I am using the following

- mysql server 5.5
- JDK 7
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.20
- apache tomcat server 7.0.27

Comment: I believe it happens because your query returns too many rows, and SQLYog either limits the number of rows it shows or displays just portion of result set as soon as possible. Also, you may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031484/why-does-sqlyog-returns-mysql-query-results-10x-faster-than-my-delphi-program

Comment: thanks for help dear , your guidance has helped me to resolve problem actually sql yog was returning only 1000 rows out of 6886 rows's of result set so final outcome comes back into application after 25 min